# Dispatching and handling a custom event from inside non-DOM object

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, video

My app needs to connect to, sync with, and work with web videos. I am writing an interface class between my app and all the web video players it might run into. The interface class will determine what kind of video player it's dealing with, set up listeners against the player object appropriate for that player, and send out normalized events for my app to listen to. For example, an html5-enabled video player can be asked for `.currentTime`, while Youtube Flash API accepts the request `.getCurrentTime()` instead.

In the example below, the interface class is listening to events such as `playing` and `seeking`, and once it hears such an event, it sends out an event of its own. The layer above it would listen to events coming from the interface, and call the appropriate functions in my app.

**The code**
In the layer between my app and the interface class:

```
var inter = new VideoInterface( TargetVideoId );
inter.addEventListener("playing", function(){ // Doesn't compile
    console.log('Heard playing from interface...');
}, false );

$(inter).bind( "isPlaying", function(evt) { // Doesn't do anything
    console.log('Heard playing from interface...');
    myApp.start();
});
```

The `VideoInterface` class, adding listeners and handlers after locating an HTML5 player:

```
$(vidId).bind({ 
    seeking: function() {
    console.log('Heard seeking, dispatching event...');
        var e = $.event({
            type: "isSeeking",
            message: "stuff",
            date: new Date()
        });
        $.trigger(e);
    }, 

    playing: function() {
    console.log('Heard playing, dispatching event...');
        $.event.trigger({
            type: "isPlaying",
            message: "stuff",
            date: new Date()
        });         
    },

    pause: function() {
    console.log('Heard pause, dispatching event...');
        $.event.trigger({
            type: "isPaused",
            message: "stuff",
            date: new Date()
        });
    }
});
```

**The problem**
I'm not sure whether the listener isn't listening, or the event isn't firing, but one way or another, the events fired from inside the interface class aren't reaching the mid-layer where they would be passed to my app. `Heard playing, dispatching event...` and the like are the only messages I see in my console -- the ones that trigger on catching the event in the mid-layer don't appear. I've read that you can't attach event listeners to variables, or objects in this case specifically, but if so, how can I accomplish the effect that I want (which, again, is for an object to send out an event that anything listening to it can catch)?

**Edit**
I've solved my problem by adding a `bindListenersFor( obj )` method to my VideoInterface class. `obj` is a reference to my app, and the interface already has an internal reference to the video object. The code now looks something like this:

```
var inter = new VideoInterface( videoReference );
var app = new App( inter );
inter.bindListenersFor( app );
```

The relevant interface code:

```
bindListenersFor : function( obj ) {
    thisClass = this;
    $(this.videoHandle).bind({ 
        seeking: function() {
            obj.seek( thisClass.getCurTime() ); 
        }, 

        playing: function() {
            obj.start();
        },

        pause: function() {
            obj.pause();
        }
    });
},

play : function() {
    this.videoHandle.play();
},

pause : function() {
    this.videoHandle.pause();
},

{ ... }
```

Now the two can talk among each other, thanks to the reference to the main app object being passed into the interface after the app itself has loaded (with the interface as one of the arguments already). Still, something about this feels inelegant, so the question of sending and listening for custom variable events remains open.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do away with trying to bind to events via jQuery and handle these custom events yourself.

Just create an empty array of methods to call whenever event X happens.

In other words:

```
function VideoInterface() {
  this.isPlayingHandlers = [];
}

var inter = new VideoInterface( TargetVideoId );    
inter.isPlayingHandlers.push(function(data) { 
    console.log('Heard playing from interface...');
});

// inside the .bind()
playing: function() {
    console.log('Heard playing, dispatching event...');
        var eventData = 'blah';
        for (var handler in inter.isPlayingHandlers)
           handler(eventData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used something like this in my eventual solution (see edit). Still, the ability to trigger custom events seems to be a more elegant and useful solution than what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

The methods you're trying to use are for DOM events. You can either use callbacks instead of events, or implement something like node's [`EventEmmiter`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/events.js).